# How could I restore a Cosmos DB container if there is a periodic backup?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, restore

Is there a way to restore a Cosmos DB container after I accidentally deleted it? I just confused the live environment with a local Cosmos DB emulator.

When I go to the **Settings** - **Backup & Restore** it says:

> Your account is on periodic backup mode. You can now change to continuous mode for a better backup and restore experience. Change to continuous mode

Does it mean that it is still somehow possible to revert the delete operation? But I can not find an option to revert the deletion.

Comment: This is a support topic (and a service-level documentation topic), not a programming question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Cosmos DB containers configured with *periodic* backup (as you've mentioned is the case here), Microsoft has [very prescriptive guidance on how to potentially restore the data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/configure-periodic-backup-restore#request-restore). TL;DR - you should file a support request with the Microsoft Azure support team **as soon as is feasible** (being sure to include all information they need as indicated in the linked article). Their word choice in the linked document strongly indicates a time-sensitive aspect to this, and a relatively short window in which you need to lodge such a request to ensure the best possible outcome.

I've reproduced the relevant bits from the linked documentation below for convenience/posterity (emphases mine):

> ### Request data restore from a backup
>
> If you accidentally delete your
> database or a container, you can file a support ticket or call the
> Azure support to restore the data from automatic online backups. **Azure
> support is available for selected plans only such as Standard,
> Developer, and plans higher than those. Azure support is not available
> with Basic plan.**
>
> To restore a specific snapshot of the backup, Azure Cosmos DB requires
> that the data is available during the backup cycle for that snapshot.
> You should have the following details before requesting a restore:
>
> - Have your subscription ID ready.
> - Based on how your data was accidentally deleted or modified, you
>   should prepare to have additional information. It is advised that you
>   have the information available ahead to minimize the back-and-forth
>   that can be detrimental in some time sensitive cases.
> - If the entire Azure Cosmos DB account is deleted, you need to provide
>   the name of the deleted account. If you create another account with
>   the same name as the deleted account, share that with the support team
>   because it helps to determine the right account to choose. It's
>   recommended to file different support tickets for each deleted account
>   because it minimizes the confusion for the state of restore.
> - If one or more databases are deleted, you should provide the Azure
>   Cosmos DB account, and the Azure Cosmos DB database names and specify
>   if a new database with the same name exists.
> - If one or more containers are deleted, you should provide the Azure
>   Cosmos DB account name, database names, and the container names. And
>   specify if a container with the same name exists.
> - If you have accidentally deleted or corrupted your data, you should
>   contact Azure support within 8 hours so that the Azure Cosmos DB team
>   can help you restore the data from the backups. Before you create a
>   support request to restore the data, make sure to increase the backup
>   retention for your account to at least seven days. It’s best to
>   increase your retention within 8 hours of this event. This way the
>   Azure Cosmos DB support team will have enough time to restore your
>   account.
>
> In addition to Azure Cosmos DB account name, database names, container
> names, you should specify the point in time to which the data can be
> restored to. It is important to be as precise as possible to help us
> determine the best available backups at that time. It is also
> important to specify the time in UTC.

Comment: Best to just link to the docs in a comment, rather than copy-pasting support docs (especially since this a support issue, and not a programming issue)